# update struct using a value from the struct itself gives: "cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable"

Tags: struct, rust, reference

I am trying to create a `struct` that modifies its `current_value` by appending some "constant" string `first_step` which is defined when the `struct` is first created.

code

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut adder = Adder {
        current_value: "init".to_string(),
        first_step: ", first".to_string(),
    };
    adder.do_something()
}

struct Adder {
    current_value: String,
    first_step: String,
}

impl Adder {
    fn add(&mut self, value: &String) {
        self.current_value = format!("{}{}", self.current_value, value);
    }

    fn do_something(&mut self) {
        // cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
        // mutable borrow occurs here rustc(E0502)
        // main.rs(24, 18): immutable borrow occurs here
        // main.rs(24, 14): immutable borrow later used by call
        self.add(&self.first_step);
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e4e609937f6f8fb0ca2c48a3e25d8764)

I think the errors are quite clear (the `self` in `self.add` is borrowed as mutable because the signature of `add` has `&mut self`, but then the value to be appended also comes from `self`, but this time borrowed as immutable, and we cannot borrow `self` both mutable and immutable).

But I don't know how to fix this, creating a data structure that can update itself with some "constant" values that are defined when the structure itself is created. In the actual "real life" case I have a `struct` that contains both a `file` and `file_header: String`, and I want to have a method that writes the `file_header` into the `file`.

Comment: I think what are you trying to achieve is called "Interior Mutability Pattern". You can wrap `current_value` with smart pointer that allows interior mutability and eliminate `&mut self`, for example like there:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=497b726e5f0753aa59924c95e3e3aaa2

Comment: or:
clone value `self.add(&self.first_step.clone());`

or event better, refactor your code:
```
fn add_first_step(&mut self) {
        self.current_value = format!("{}{}", self.current_value, self.first_step);
    }

    fn do_something(&mut self) {
        self.add_first_step();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust *does* allow for borrowing *parts* of a `struct` separately, but when you call a function/method that takes `&mut Self`, that always borrows the entire `struct` — the body of the function is never used as additional information. So, a solution to problems like where you want to mutate part of your structure using information from another part is to rewrite your function signature so that it *does* have the necessary information.

```rust
impl Adder {
    /// Algorithm implementation; takes all components explicitly.
    /// Is not a method.
    fn add_impl(current_value: &mut String, add_value: &str) {
        current_value.push_str(add_value);
    }

    /// Method for external use — less flexible, but simple.
    pub fn add(&mut self, value: &str) {
        Self::add_impl(&mut self.current_value, value);
    }

    fn do_something(&mut self) {
        Self::add_impl(&mut self.current_value, &self.first_step);
    }

}
```

Your description “…a data structure that can update itself with some "constant" values that are defined when the structure itself is created…” suggests that you might have a more complicated situation than this simple example. If you have more than one mutable field that needs updating (or even if you really want to use method syntax), you can make another `struct` that contains the right subset of fields — then the methods like `do_something` can call ordinary `&mut self` methods on the inner struct.

```rust
struct FancyAdder {
    first_step: String,
    data: AdderData,
}

struct AdderData {
    current_value: String,
    ...
}

impl FancyAdder {
    fn do_something(&mut self) {
       // This borrows `self.data` mutably and `self.first_step` immutably.
       // No overlap.
       self.data.add(&self.first_step);
    }
}

impl AdderData {
    fn add(&mut self, value: &str) {
        self.current_value.push_str(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: excellent. Thanks Kevin for the clear explanation (and for the `push_str`). If I can rephrase this: the core issue is the the immutable data (`first_step`) was part of the "ownership tree" (is there a proper name?) of the mutable data (`self`). This was not necessary, and so a finer isolation of the mutable part (`current_value`) solves the problem.

Comment: @user103716 Yes, exactly. I don't know of a specific term for the "ownership tree".