# Error with Rayon, cannot borrow `*self` as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure

Tags: rust, rayon

First of all, I'm new toRust. For a game I'm working on I need to call function to change pixels on a vector that is then transformed into an iamge. For that, I have a struct that contains all the context of the game, include said image and everything I need to calcaulate the pixels.

This works with a single thread but not when I try to parallelize it with Rayon.

Here's a simplified code as an example of the problem. It works with `chunks_mut`.

```
use ::rayon::prelude::*;
struct Game {
    pub pixel: [u8; 4],
    pub pixel_vec: Vec<u8>,
}

impl Game {
    pub fn new(pixel: [u8; 4], length: usize) -> Self {
        let pixel_vec = vec![2; length];

        Self { pixel, pixel_vec }
    }
    pub fn draw(&mut self) {
        let mut pixel_vec = std::mem::take(&mut self.pixel_vec);

        pixel_vec
            .par_chunks_mut(4)
            .for_each(|slice| self.some_function(slice));
        self.pixel_vec = pixel_vec;
    }

    fn some_function(&mut self, slice: &mut [u8]) {
        for i in 0..slice.len() {
            slice[i] = self.pixel[i] * self.pixel[i];
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut game = Game::new([0, 3, 0, 0], 20);
    game.draw();
}
```

Error

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure
  --> src/main.rs:18:31
   |
18 |             .for_each(|slice| self.some_function(slice));
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0596`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Comment: Note that in the code you posted, `some_function` does not need `self` to be mutable: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=30092d2948cd229137a142a870e4c289)

Comment: Very relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67027724

Answer (score 1):

Your `Game::some_function` function uses the `&mut self` receiver. This means that it must borrow `self` mutably. That is, `self.some_function(slice)` is the same as `Game::some_function(&mut self, slice)`.

So when you call `self.some_function(slice)` in your closure, the closure must capture `self` as mutable, since it needs to borrow `self` as mutable to call the function. However, the `for_each` function requires a `Fn` closure and a `Fn` closure will not let you capture as mutable (for good reason).

The solution in your case is to change the receiver in `some_function` to `&self`, since as written that function doesn't need mutable access to `self`:

```rust
fn some_function(&self, slice: &mut [u8]) {
    // ...
}
```

---

Edit:

To complete the explanation: the rayon [`par_chunks_mut`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/slice/trait.ParallelSliceMut.html#method.par_chunks_mut) method returns a type that implements [`ParallelIterator`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html), which is where the `for_each` method comes from. That's where the argument implementing `Fn` is required.

Now thinking about the [available closure traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch13-01-closures.html) in Rust, why `Fn`? Well the other options are `FnOnce` or `FnMut`. `FnOnce` consumes the closure when called once and thus can only be called at most once (hence the name), clearly this isn't going to work for a `for_each` method. `FnMut` is weaker, it *can* capture variables mutably, so why does rayon not use that? The entire point is to call this closure concurrently in different threads, which you can't do if you're mutating its state, you'd have to synchronise the mutable access which would effectively serialise the operation, making the whole thing a waste of time. Thus, `Fn` is the only option and no mutable captures are allowed.